# Failed to resolve com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0 in gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I apologize if I am missing something obvious, but I recently converted my project from Eclipse to Android Studio (and Gradle) and am trying to add support for Floating Action Buttons using [Melnykov's library](https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton), but Gradle cannot resolve it. I thought it was a simple matter of adding `compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'` to my app's `build.gradle` file. Am I missing something or is the source not available to download or what? Thanks ahead of time.

My app's `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
    compile files('libs/opencsv-3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}
```

And the error I get is

> Error:(6, 13) Failed to resolve:
>   com.makovkastar:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the *repository* from which gradle should download the aar.

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

**Without this part, gradle doesn't know where to find the dependencies.**

The other libraries don't need the repo because they are local jars (they can be found in the lib folder):

```
compile files('libs/opencsv-3.1.jar')
```

or a local maven (provided with the sdk manager)

```
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to have been resolved after adding the jcenter repository like this. I don't fully understand it, but everything compiles now.

```
...
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0'
    compile files('libs/opencsv-3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
...
```